# How to use nest in d3 to group using the 'month' as key, but my csv file contains the whole date?

Tags: date, csv, d3.js

```
           var data = d3.nest()
          .key(function(d) { return d.date;})
          .rollup(function(d) { 
           return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.something; });
          }).entries(csv_data);
```

using this code above I can group by date which is in the format yyyy-mm-dd , but I want to group using the month as key. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the key function to return the value you want to nest by.  In most cases, the key function just returns a property of the data object (like `d.date`), but in your case the function will require a little more calculation.

If your date is stored as a string of the format "yyyy-mm-dd" you have two options for extracting the month: either

- use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to extract the portion of the string in between the "-" characters, or
- convert it to a [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and use date methods to extract a component of the date.

Browsers differ in which date formats they can convert using the native Javascript `new Date(string)` constructor, so if you're using date objects you may want to use a [d3 date format function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)'s `format.parse(string)` method to be sure of consistent results.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the builtin method `d3.timeMonth()` to get the first day of the month for a date like:

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d){ return d3.timeMonth(d.date); });
```

If `d.date` is not already a javascript `Date` object you have to first parse it to be one.

```
var date_format =  d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
csv_data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.date = date_format.parse(d.date);
};
```